# xamarin android insert image into online database and show it in image view form the same data base but different devices

Tags: android, xamarin

i have an app that works online and with online web services and online database my problem is i want to insert image into my database and show the image in imageview for all other devices that have installed the app not just locally here is the table of my database that i'm trying to insert image into it

```
[dbo].[Product](
[Product_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Product_Shop_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Product_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Product_Price] [float] NOT NULL,
[Product_Image] [image] NULL,
[Expiry_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

and here is my web services method o add to the table

```
 public string AddProduct(int Product_ID, string Product_Name, float Product_Price, DateTime Expiry_Date,int Product_Quantity,Image Product_Image)
    {
        /* int Product_Shop_ID =  getshopid();*/
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Product (Product_ID,Product_Shop_ID,Product_Name,Product_Price,Expiry_Date,Product_Quantity,Product_Image) VALUES (@Product_ID,@Product_Name,@Product_Price,@Expiry_Date,@Product_Quantity,@Product_Image)");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_ID", Product_ID);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Shop_ID", Product_Shop_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", Product_Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Price", Product_Price);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expiry_Date", Expiry_Date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Quantity", Product_Quantity);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Image", Product_Image);
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                return "Product Added Sucssesfuly";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
            //return "Some Thing Went Worng Please Check Your Information And Try Agin!";
        }
    }
```

and her is my xaml code for mainactivity layout

```
(<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:text="insert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1100px"
    android:id="@+id/button1" />
<TextView
    android:text="id"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />
<TextView
    android:text="shop id"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100px"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />
<TextView
    android:text="name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="200px"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
<TextView
    android:text="price"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="300px"
    android:id="@+id/textView4" />
<TextView
    android:text="date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="400px"
    android:id="@+id/textView5" />
<TextView
    android:text="quantity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="500px"
    android:id="@+id/textView6" />
<Button
    android:text="image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="600px"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="800px"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
```

)

and here is he code that select image from gallery in the class of mainactivity layout

```
(    namespace imagetest
```

{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

```
    public static readonly int PickImageId = 1000;
    private ImageView selectedimage;
    Button button;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
        selectedimage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        button.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent = new Intent();
        Intent.SetType("image/*");
        Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);

    }
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {

    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

})

**in my code up there i just pick the image but i need away to insert the image i picked it from  the Button_Click into the database in a type that i can retrieve it later to show it in imageview  **

Comment: Help with what?  You haven't asked a question or described any problems that you're having.  Do you get errors or exceptions?  What **specifically** do you need help with?

Comment: sorry @Jason i have update my question now i hop you can help me with that to find code makes me insert the image into database and retrieve it from database and show it in imageview

Comment: i have tried storing it by using uri and it works and seve the image as string but when i call it back to show it from other device that i insert the image from it it shows me this error (java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{3a5e86d 2915:jeremy.com.wineofmine/u0a321} (pid=2915, uid=10321) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs)

Comment: you can't take the local url of an image and expect that to work on another device.  You need to upload the image data (typically as a byte[]) and store it on the server.  There are numerous other questions on SO that show how to do this.

Comment: thank you i have  changed it to base 64 and it works good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the image to base64 string,then save the base64String to the sqlite.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
 if (requestCode == PickImageId &&
          resultCode == (int)Result.Ok &&
          data != null &&
          data.Data != null)
        {
            filePath = data.Data;       
            Bitmap mBitMap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(Activity.ContentResolver, filePath);
            string base64String = ConvertBitmapToString(mBitMap); //save the base64String
        }
}

public static string ConvertBitmapToString(Bitmap bitmap)
    {

        byte[] bitmapData;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50, stream);
            bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
        }

        string ImageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bitmapData);

        return ImageBase64;
    }

public static Bitmap ConvertStringToBitmap(string mystr)
    {
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.Decode(mystr, Base64.Default);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.Length);

        return decodedByte;
    }
```

Comment: will thanks a lot that works for me for storing the  image  but in ConvertStringToBitmap method some libraries is missing so i added 
using Android.Graphics;; for Bitmap , 
using Java.Util; for Base64 , but it shows me error on Base64.Default says (base64 does not contain definition for default) what do  i missing here ??

Comment: @BaselAlbasha you need use `Android.Util` for `Base64`.